# In a paragraph about a paper, where do I put the citation?

Tags: citations, citation-style

I have a paragraph about a specific method used by an author and I am wondering where in that paragraph I should put my inline citation.

The paragraph in question goes something like this, where *steps to complete the method* is several sentences summarizing the paper.

> The Harman method was devised by T. C. Harman .... 
>   *steps to complete the method* ....
>   Harman showed that ZT could be computed from eq. (2.1)

Where should I put the citation?  I see three options:

1. at the beginning (right after the name)
2. at the end of the first sentence
3. at the end of the paragraph

Or some combination of the three options above. I am using IEEE citation format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel that it is best to cite once for each unique referent. In your case, you are referring first to a set of methods, and later to a result. Thus I would write

> The Harman method (Harman, DATE) was devised by T. C. Harman .... *steps to complete
>   the method* .... Harman showed that ZT could be computed from eq. (2.1) (Harman, DATE)

Comment: Do you mean that "methods _was_" is intentional?

Comment: No, I just copied the OP's text. Fixed.

Comment: It might be better to fix it the other way round, afaik there is only one Harman method for the determination of the figure of merit ZT of a thermoelectric material. I'm not sure however whether there are more papers to be cited.